# (Pulp)how to create a constraint so that if value is greater than 0 then it must be greater than 5000 as well

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm resolving problem of transport Optimization with Pulp where I have certain factories and orders, and based on the transportation cost for each factory, I must generate the best optimization aiming at cost minimization.
My algorithm works, but I need to create a constraint so that, if there is movement to a factory, the minimum movement must be 5000, for example.
[value is less than 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Veu.png)

```
from pulp import *

capacityFactory = {
    "Factory01": 56000, 
    "Factory02": 50000, 
    "Factory03": 40000, 
    "Factory04": 30000,
    "Factory05": 37000,
    "Factory06": 42000,
    "Factory07": 45000,
    "Factory08": 52000,
    "Factory09": 57000
}
factories = capacityFactory.keys()

orderBalance = {
    "Order01": 14000,
    "Order02": 35000,
    "Order03": 76000,
    "Order04": 36000,
    "Order05": 72000,
    "Order06": 41000,
    "Order07": 12000,
    "Order08": 56000,
    "Order09": 10000,
    "Order10": 7000
}
orders = orderBalance.keys()

# Creates a list of cost of each transportation path
cost = [  # orders
    [3.26, 9.31, 8.49, 5.96, 8.61, 5.45, 6.2, 7.31, 4.89, 8.34], # A   factories
    [5.5, 8.75, 9.67, 5.05, 8.54, 5.5, 6.3, 7.36, 4.35, 8.51],  # B
    [4.66, 8.36, 8.13, 4.33, 8.59, 5.6, 6.4, 7.42, 4.91, 9.71], # C
    [1.66, 1.36, 1.88, 2.77, 100, 5.65, 6.5, 7.89, 5.21, 7.01],   # D
    [2.456, 6.54, 7.4, 3.54, 7.98, 5.44, 6.4, 7.89, 5.21, 7.01],   # E
    [3.54, 6.98, 8.24, 3.12, 7.77, 5.12, 6.52, 7.12, 5.16, 7.5],   # F
    [2.15, 4.54, 7.87, 3.15, 7.45, 5.396, 6.98, 7.02, 5, 7.4],   # G
    [2.48, 5.55, 8.341, 3.19, 7.48, 5.9, 6.21, 7.23, 5.08, 7.36],   # H
    [3.41, 5.69, 8.14, 3.22, 7.66, 5.87, 6.35, 8.23, 5.39, 7.99],   # I
]
cost = makeDict([factories, orders], cost, 0)
prob = LpProblem("Material capacityFactory Problem", LpMinimize)
Routes = [(w, b) for w in factories for b in orders]
vars = LpVariable.dicts("Receive", (factories, orders), 0, None, LpInteger)

prob += (
    lpSum([vars[w][b] * cost[w][b] for (w, b) in Routes]),
    "Sum_of_Transporting_cost",
)

# The capacityFactory maximum constraints are added to prob for each capacityFactory node (factories)
for w in factories:
    prob += (
        lpSum([vars[w][b] for b in orders]) <= capacityFactory[w],
        "Sum_of_Products_out_of_factories_%s" % w,
    )

# The orderBalance minimum constraints are added to prob for each orderBalance node (project)
for b in orders:
    prob += (
        lpSum([vars[w][b] for w in factories]) >= orderBalance[b],
        "Sum_of_Products_into_orders%s" % b,
    )

# Add non-negativity constraints for all variables
for w in factories:
    for b in orders:
        prob += (
            vars[w][b] >= 0,
            "Non_Negative_%s_to_%s" % (w, b),
        )

prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
    
print("Value of Objective Function = ", value(prob.objective))
```

How can i do this constraint using Pulp?

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[pulp](/questions/tagged/pulp)[linear-programming](/questions/tagged/linear-programming)[optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization)

Comment: Note that the condition, as phrased, doesn't make a lot of sense. Rephrase it: values have to be either less than or equal to 0, or greater than 5000.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is implementation of "semi-continuous" variables where the variable is either 0 or within some range.  There are many examples on this site.

I'm assuming that a factory is either not used at all or must be used for at least 5000 orders of any type, so...

Essentially you want to :

Introduce another binary indicator variable to indicate whether a factory is used at all for any order

```
use[factory]   ∈ {0, 1}   1 if used, 0 else
```

Then you need to constrain the factory's activity to zero or the relevant range *for each factory*

```
∑ receive[factory, order] for all orders ≤ use[factory] * max_orders[factory]
```

and

```
∑ receive[factory, order] for all orders ≥ use[factory] * min_orders[factory]
```

I would also encourage you to consider making `receive` a continuous variable rather than integer if your program starts to slow down.  Solving with continuous variables is always faster and when the numbers are "large" in the 10,000's in your case, usually a continuous approximation is OK.